# How to filter messages in Kafka consumer based on header value at listener level in Springboot?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I want to filter Kafka messages at listener level based on Kafka Header Values.

I have tried to use a custom KafkaConsumerConfig.java. Please look into the below file

```
package com.example.test.consumer;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.header.Header;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
    private String group_id;
    
    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrap_server;

    @Bean
    ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrap_server);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, group_id);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setRecordFilterStrategy(consumerRecord -> {
            if (consumerRecord.headers().lastHeader("CUSTOM_HEADER").key().equals("VALID")) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
        return factory;
    }
}
```

But the application is failing to start with the below reason..

> Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 20 due to node -1 being disconnected

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring, or filtering; you have broker connectivity problems. It's better to use a more meaningful title on questions; you also need to provide much more information - for example, can you connect to the broker using command line tools? If you are using docker, you need to provide the config.

Comment: I was able to filter kafka messages based on header by referring to the below example:
https://prateek-ashtikar512.medium.com/kafka-message-filter-c8ae1dca53f3

Comment: Feel free to provide a full example below as an answer rather than comment with link to external site